# Reading words from one file and grep them in another file

Tags: python

I want to pick words from one file and grep them in another file using python. The code looks like

```
f1 = open("file1.txt",'r')
f2 = open("file2.txt",'r')

def find_word(str, fp):
    for line in fp:
        if line == str:
            print (line)

for word in f1:
    find_word(word, f2)
```

While I am sure that some words exists in file2.txt, nothing is printed. What is wrong with that snippet?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the value of `line` might be?

Comment: Something like `/*0040*/                   MOV R4, 0x0 ;                             /* 0x0000000000047802 */` and I grep for MOV

Comment: So are you asking why the strings `"/*0040*/ MOV R4, 0x0 ; /* 0x0000000000047802 */\n"` and `"MOV"` aren't equal?

Comment: No. Why `find_word("MOV", f2)` returns nothing while f2 is the file that contains `/*0040*/ MOV R4, 0x0 ; /* 0x0000000000047802 */`?

Comment: See my answer, but the gist is that `==` will require the strings to match exactly. In the example given you're performing the comparison I stated earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the function `find_word`:

```py
def find_word(str, fp):
    for line in fp:
        if line == str:
            print (line)
```

This iterates over each line in the file given by `fp` (or any iterable for that matter). Unless the string `str` matches a line in the file exactly (including a newline character, if applicable), your function won't print anything. You may want to check if its in that line instead, say with

```py
def find_word(str, fp):
    for line in fp:
        if str in line:
            print (line)
```

or better yet, as `str` is a built-in class

```py
def find_word(query, fp):
    for line in fp:
        if query in line:
            print (line)
```

---

You also probably want to strip the newline from `word` in

```py
for word in f1:
    find_word(word, f2)
```

so instead it might look like

```py
for word in f1:
    find_word(word.rstrip('\r\n'), f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You consume the entire input file the first time you search for a word. Subsequent searches will fail because `for line in file` will return nothing.

If you are searching for words within a line, that will fail too, because to line you read includes the terminating newline; so

```
if 'word\n' in line:
```

will not find `word` if it is not immediately adjacent to the end of the line.